# How can I use VLOOKUP to return ANY different result?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've been trying to find if `VLOOKUP` (or any other combination of functions) can be used to check a table for matching results, and display "No" if any of the matching results have a "No" in a specific column.

Example:

- Column A is different meals (repeated per ingredient)
- Column B is ingredients
- Column C is if they are vegetarian

Is there a formula I can use to check if any of column **C = "No"** within each meal, and return "No"?

Comment: I think I know exactly what you're trying to accomplish. If you can add an example of your data, I think I have a much simpler way for you to determine your daily pars. :)  (Short answer: pivot table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VLOOKUP` function will ALWAYS return the first matched value (reading top down). You can use `COUNTIFS` to accomplish this. You will need to enter the meal you are looking for in quotes in the 2nd criteria of the equation (or more realistically just reference your cell with the meal in question).

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, MEAL, C:C, "No")
```

This will return the count of combinations that meet your criteria. To return "Yes" / "No", you can nest this formula inside of an `IF` statement.

```
IF(COUNTIFS(A:A, MEAL, C:C, "No") > 0, "Yes", "No")
```

Returns `Yes` if any given meal is related to a "No" comment, returns `No` if there is no combination of a given meal and "No"